# Integrate rails 4 application with alfersco

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want documentation future in my rails application so, I use REST api for integrating rails application with alfersco. But I need guide for how REST api work for integration and also need there is any cost for access the alfersco functionalities like documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample [project](https://github.com/trevmex/active-alfresco).

And this is developer [guide](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-for-developers.html)

Yes,there is cost for access the alfersco functionalities:)

You can check [this](https://reviews.financesonline.com/p/alfresco/)

Comment: you there @Narayanan

Comment: Thank you  @karthick nagarajan

Comment: Are you check it?

Comment: I could not able to run the sample project as you gave because it does not contain the gem file. I just read the developer guide and cost of access its more helpful. Can you give the details of how to purchase secret key to access cloud services in alfersco. Thank you @karthick nagarajan